# Internationalization of an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, internationalization, rcp

I have a problem with internationalization (I18n).

I have followed almost all the tutorials I could find , I have created a message.java file , message_en.properties , and message_de.properties, but the problem is I don't know what to write inside my main class to call the budles.

I mean when I click on a button , my plugin language should change from English to German.

What should I do ?

Comment: You need to call whatever function that's setting the texts in your labels or whatever is internationalized again when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a button that changes the languages instantly, a restart is needed for the plugin to reload the bundles.

Changing the locale programatically isn't easy. The simplest way seems to be to change the `yourproduct.ini` file (or `config.ini` in your plugin) in order to change the language. For example :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-nl
it
-vmargs
-Xmx1024m
-Xms412M
```

The important config is `-nl it` (for Italian here). You need to restart Eclipse/your product after that of course.

Here's the most complete tutorial I know regarding i18n in RCP applications : http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseInternationalization/article.html#i18n_osgi